# Notification android 5. Status bar icon is empty and on large icon notification icon is empty

Tags: notifications, android-5.0-lollipop

I use a notifications in my application. At the moment, I was faced with the problem of displaying icons for Android L. For devices 4.4 and below, all is well. I used the icon sizes: large - icon 64 dp, icon status bar - 24 dp. Devices android L icon status bar is displayed as a white square that is missing:

[image]

On the notification on the large icon appeared empty icon:

[image]

I want to notification my android l looked like this:

[image]

And status bar icon on android L will be visible.
My code:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notification_small)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.icon_notification);)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(content))
                    .setPriority(2)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setTicker(ticker)
                    .setContentText(content);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example you provided they are calling:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notification_small)
                .setColor(resources.getColor(R.color.icon_notification_background_color))
                ...
```

Note that they are NOT calling `.setLargeIcon`

Comment: I solved this problem by simply removing targetSdk from AndroidManifest.xml. I know that this is not the best way, but it works

Comment: That sounds really hacky and is clearly not maintainable. How about just removing the call to `setLargeIcon`?

Comment: I am having the same issue. However when I remove .setlargeicon the icon appears very small in the normal notification view. It is surrounded by a grey circle...